# Разделение бизнес-логики и логики замера времени выполнения

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

Мне нужно замерить время выполнения определенных методов. Однако, замеры времени сильно захламляют логику и делают метод малочитаемым:

```java
public void method() {
    StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
    sw.start();
    innerMethod1();
    sw.stop();
    Monitoring.add("eventType1", sw.getLastTaskTimeMillis());

    sw.start();
    innerMethod2("abs");
    sw.stop();
    Monitoring.add("eventType2", sw.getLastTaskTimeMillis());

    sw.start();
    innerMethod3(5, 29);
    sw.stop();
    Monitoring.add("eventType3", sw.getLastTaskTimeMillis());
}
```

Поскольку это приватные методы и вызываются они внутри класса, поэтому Spring AOP мне не подходит.
AspectJ сильно меня смущает необходимостью использования дополнительных ключей
[согласно статье на habr](https://habr.com/ru/post/347752/).
Есть ли какие-то другие способы разделить логику?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно отдельный метод создать для замеров времени, а на вход ему передавать объект `Runnable` с кодом, время выполнения которого нужно замерить:

```java
private static void benchmark(String text, int iterations, Runnable runnable) {
    long counter;
    long avgCounter = 0;

    System.out.print(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        counter = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Код, время выполнения
        // которого будем замерять
        runnable.run();

        counter = System.currentTimeMillis() - counter;
        System.out.print(" | " + counter);
        avgCounter += counter;

        // Вызываем garbage collector
        System.gc();
    }
    System.out.println(" || " + avgCounter / iterations);
}
```

Пример вызова:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int iterations = 10;

    benchmark("eventType1", iterations, () -> {
        // do something
        method1();
        method2();
    });

    benchmark("eventType2", iterations, () -> {
        // do something
        method3();
        method4();
    });

    // . . .
}
```

Вывод:

```
eventType1 | 109 | 109 | 108 | 108 | 108 | 108 | 109 | 108 | 109 | 108 || 108
eventType2 | 108 | 108 | 108 | 109 | 109 | 108 | 108 | 108 | 108 | 108 || 108
```

---

**Примечание:** код выполняется в текущем потоке. Многопоточность **не** используется.